# Using Python to fill .swf (Flash) web form?

Tags: python, forms, flash, python-2.7, web-crawler

This project is most likely attempting the impossible, but I feel determined to try.

First of all, Fedex has a form on their website for quoting rates and transit times. (https://www.fedex.com/ratefinder/home) After studying the page with Chrome Developer Tools I found that the form is an embedded SWF.

My goal is to write a Python script which will fill out the Flash form, submit the form and capture the resulting text. I have written Python scripts for web crawling, submitting POST data, handling secure sessions, but never have I touched a Flash form.

Any ideas? (By the way, I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7)

Comment: When I go to that rate finder link on my phone I see an HTML version. You might explore doing this with HTML. I used to do a lot of this type of stuff with Perl's LWP module (basically a scriptable web browser). Perhaps Python has a similar browser...

Comment: Thanks, and I should have posted this but it slipped my mind. If you have a user account, the form is an embedded SWF. If you don't have an account, the form is HTML. I think it has to do with pulling customer information from a database and applying discounts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `flash-selenium` and `flex-ui-selenium` plug-ins for `seleniumHQ` should allow you to drive a compatible browser into anything it's able to do.

Comment: seleniumHQ is a Firefox IDE addon. There _is_ a Selenium module for Python, but the code is aged and I have found no usable examples. Thanks for the answer though, I may have to ditch Python altogether and just use the Selenium IDE.